# SWD debugging for Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero, bare-metal, debug

I am developing a bare metal program that will be run on a Raspberry Pi Zero board.

Is it possible to debug the program with the SWD protocol?

Are RPi0/1 boards (which are based on BCM2835 SoC) able to use the SWD protocol?

I am aware that BCM2835 supports jtag debugging, but SWD is preferred because it uses fewer pins.